# Why am I getting a format/extension error when appending to an xls file with AutoHotkey?

Tags: excel, autohotkey

I was appending to a ***.csv*** file with no problems.

Instead, I want to append to an ***.xlsx*** file, because I want to be able to make a nice looking table.

Unfortunately, upon opening the **xlsx** file, I am getting this message:

*"Excel cannot open the file 'printlog.xls' because the file format or the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."*

It does not do this with a **csv** file.

There is no official documentation on the AHK website that says it is possible to FileAppend to ***.xlsx*** format, but there are plenty of examples online of people doing so.

Here is my code:

```
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

ControlGetText, test, Edit10, TeamViewer

filename = %A_ScriptDir%\printlog.xlsx

FileAppend,
(
%test%,%test%,%test%,%test%
%test%,%test%,%test%,%test%
), %filename%
```

UPDATE: the first portion of this has been solved thanks to @user3419297's solution. I have a new problem listed below.

```
FilePath := A_ScriptDir "\printlog.xlsx"   ; get file path
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%                ; set working directory

ControlGetText, itemcode, Edit1, Print -   ; get item code from print menu
ControlGetText, quantity, Edit2, Print -   ; get quantity from print menu
ControlGetText, amount, Edit3, Print -     ; get amount from print menu
ControlGetText, initials, Edit4, Print -   ; get quantity from print menu
ControlGetText, info, Edit5, Print -       ; get quantity from print menu
ControlGetText, batch, Edit6, Print -      ; get quantity from print menu

Formattime,ts,,Shortdate                   ; generate short date variable

oExcel := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")  ; create Excel COM object
oWorkbook := oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FilePath) ; open workbook in Excel object
oExcel.Visible := false                      ; work in background

                                               ; check for blank rows and append values
For Row in oExcel.Range["A1"]                  ; starting with the first row
{
        If (Row.Value = "")                        ; if first row is blank
        {
                oExcel.Range("A1").Value := %itemcode% ; set value of cell A-G
                oExcel.Range("B1").Value := %quantity%
                oExcel.Range("C1").Value := %amount%
                oExcel.Range("D1").Value := %initials%
                oExcel.Range("E1").Value := %info%
                oExcel.Range("F1").Value := %batch%
                oExcel.Range("G1").Value := %ts%
        }
        else ; else find the next blank row and set values of A-G
        For eachRow in oExcel.Range["A1:A" oExcel.Columns("A").Find[""].Row]
        {
        If (eachRow.Value = "")
            {
                        oExcel.Range("A" . A_Index).Value := %itemcode%
                        oExcel.Range("B" . A_Index).Value := %quantity%
                        oExcel.Range("C" . A_Index).Value := %amount%
                        oExcel.Range("D" . A_Index).Value := %initials%
                        oExcel.Range("E" . A_Index).Value := %info%
                        oExcel.Range("F" . A_Index).Value := %batch%
                        oExcel.Range("G" . A_Index).Value := %ts%
                        break
            }
        }
}
oWorkbook.Save() ; save workbook and close excel
oExcel.Quit()
```

[image: error image]

as you can see the error that I am getting is an illegal character. I don't understand because the contents of the variable is the string. Does this have something to do with the format of the variable in itself, or is it the format in which it is being appended to the excel file?

Comment: Changing the name of a file does not change its format. You will need to open the csv and resave it as an xlsx

Comment: I understand this, however, to clarify, I am not intending to use AHK to convert my csv into an xlsx file. What I am trying to do is append the data to an excel file *instead of* to a csv file. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @NikkiLuzader No, it does not make sense.  The method of `append` when it relates to a `CSV` type file does not mean its the same method to appending to a file with format `xlsx` as it is an XML-ish format instead.

Comment: If you want to check the file without wikipedia-ing file format/structure.. try this... open a small csv file with notepad.. see the content. It is easily append-able. Try yo open xlsx.. you cannot read the data.. so it is not straightforwardly append-able. Xlsx format is like a zip format.. you can open an xlsx file with winrar / winzip / 7z to have a look.. it IS a collection of xml files.. || that’s why you have to ‘extract’ the xml 1st before adding rows/columns of data into it.. unlike csv.. you can just add row/cols of data by just adding some ‘comma separated value’ at the end of file.

Comment: @p._phidot_ what about using ***.xls*** instead of ***.xlsx*** ? would it be feasible to use this format instead?

Comment: its the same, you still have to 'unpack' the xml data 1st (xls) before appending to it.. and then 're-pack' the xml.. || for xlsx.. add one more extra step : unzip/re-zip. ( :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append text to an .xlsx file, you have to use COM:

```
test := "my text"

FilePath := A_ScriptDir "\printlog.xlsx"
oExcel := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")
oWorkbook := oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
oExcel.Visible := false
oExcel.Range("A1").Value := test
oWorkbook.Save()
oExcel.Quit()
```

Another example:

Append the first 3 words of the copied text to the next empty row in their respective columns a,b,c:

```
FilePath := A_ScriptDir "\printlog.xlsx"

Array:=[]
Array := StrSplit(clipboard, " ")

oExcel := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")
oWorkbook := oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
oExcel.Visible := false
For Row in oExcel.Range["A1"]
{
    If (Row.Value = "")
     {
        oExcel.Range("A1").Value := Array[1]
        oExcel.Range("B1").Value := Array[2]
        oExcel.Range("C1").Value := Array[3]
    }
    else
    For eachRow in oExcel.Range["A1:A" oExcel.Columns("A").Find[""].Row]
    {
     If (eachRow.Value = "")
       {
            oExcel.Range("A" . A_Index).Value := Array[1]
            oExcel.Range("B" . A_Index).Value := Array[2]
            oExcel.Range("C" . A_Index).Value := Array[3]
                break
        }
    }
}
oWorkbook.Save()
oExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: This works perfect for changing the contents of the range A1, but what I want to do, is ***append*** values to the next empty cell. I actually want to specifically append variables x,y,z to the next row in their respective columns a,b,c. is this possible?

Comment: Try something like the second eample in my edited answer.

Comment: This worked! Thank you SO much! I can plug in variables into the array rather then using what is on the clipboard, correct?

Comment: I've found a better way to get the next empty row. Try my edited answer

Comment: Even better! I like how this one doesn't require an *ini* file, but not I know a little bit more about how *ini* files work and what they can be used for thanks to your original example(which I saved). I am going to update the issue because what I am using this for is a print log and I got an error saying that my variable contains an illegal character

Comment: `oExcel.Range("A1").Value := itemcode` is an [expression](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions), any variable names in its parameter should not be enclosed in percent signs.

Answer (score 1):

For your second problem with the screenshot it is easy, as I made this one a lot of time...

This :

```
oExcel.Range("A1").Value := %itemcode%
```

Means : take the value of the variable which the name is the content of the variable itemcode ("this. is. a. test." I guess ?).

It cannot work in your case.
Example :

```
itemcode := "A B"
msgbox %itemcode% ; display will be : A B
```

So this :

```
Test := %itemcode%
```

is the same as :

```
Test = %A B%
```

Not compiling. :-)
So you need to remove the % % unless you have dynamic variables (rarely the case) so you store their name in an other variable (varception ?).

```
oExcel.Range("A1").Value := itemcode
```